# Use Office 365 account to login to Windows 10

Tags: active-directory, windows-10-preview, office365, azure

Windows 10 has a new feature where you should be able to use our Office 365 Active Directory account to login.

This is the feature:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_apps-insider_other/windows-10-needs-to-have-office-365-accounts-as/08e0d6da-acfd-4808-9280-d084ef818f27
(Scroll all the way down)

When I try to do this, I always get this message:

> Confirm you are using the correct sign-in info, and that your
>   workplace uses this feature. Also the connection to your workplace
>   might not work right now. Please wait and try again.

I've tried it over the last 3 days, so I don't think this is the issue.
I've connected Office 365 with our Azure Active Directory.

Anyone got this to work? Do I miss an Azure configuration setting?

Comment: It's a fresh installation. What do you mean by "your active domain is specially an Azure Active Domain"?
It's an office 365 subscription that I've added to the Azure Active Directories.

Comment: Are your Office365 and / or Windows accounts "Personal" or "Business" subscriptions? In my experience the two are completely incompatible with each other, to the point of not even recognising the other's existence

Comment: They are Business. And yes, we had a mess with that too. But as I pointed out below, we did get it working. A setting in our Azure instance was missing.

Comment: you can post what you did as an answer and then mark the question as solved - might help other people with the same problem (and earn you rep points, and make people less likely to keep trying to help `:-D`)

Comment: Absolutely, unfortunately I played around with everything and really don't know anymore what setting made the difference :-(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes the issue was resolved, but changed a variety of things and does not recall which setting it was that resolved the issue.

Comment: Actually, situation with Windows has changed so much in the last few years, that this has never been an issue anymore. So, yeah, we can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Being that this is an older question I recommend deploying the RTM build.

You should be able to logon to Azure AD with the same account to verify it's access.  Be sure you don't require device registration (until you confirmed this works) - after which you can require devices be registered to access content and T/S any policies you may have applied.

Comment: Thanks. We got it working. I had to adjust a setting in Azure to enable this.

Comment: @Remy If you think that information can serve others, please add an answer of your own to the question. You can even mark it as the correct answer after 2 days IIRC